# IE 10 canvas. How to solve errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I made re-direct from one web application to second (asp + js). In chrome browser everything is all right, but in IE I get an error.

I read about a solution here: https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/wiki/Instructions

so I added this:

```
type="text/javascript" src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js

type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.min.js"
```

and declare canvas and cxt like this:

```
canvas = document.createElement("gameCanvas");
G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
var cxt= canvas.getContext("2d");
    var ctx= canvas.getContext("2d");
```

but I still receive this error:

> (getcontext object doesn support this property or method)
>   http://oi42.tinypic.com/25t9oix.jpg

The strange situation to me is that in IE, when I open the html application file, I don't get errors and the application runs well.  But when I redirect to this file from app in localhost (IIS), then I have all these problems.

Have you got any idea what more I can do?

Comment: what is a `gameCanvas`? As far as I know, that should be `document.createElement('canvas')`

Comment: Why are you using a minified library during development? And what happened to your question title? It doesn't make any sense!

Comment: `gameCanvas` becouse

`<body onLoad="init();">
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="500" style="background-color: black;">`


I tried with excanvas.min.js and excanvas.js the effect was the same.

Comment: Please be more specific in your question, also, some HTML source would be helpful to help you debug your code

Comment: My question is what I'm doing wrong in adjusting canvas to IE 10?

http://sharetext.org/XXzm

Answer (score 1):

First, IE10 support canvas elements. The problem is right there:

```
document.createElement("gameCanvas");
```

document.createElement expect to receive "div", "span", "canvas", etc. Not an id.
 In your comment, you said that you have set your canvas in your html file like this:

```
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="500" style="background-color: black;">
```

So you do not want to create this element, you want to retrieve it like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var cxt= canvas.getContext("2d");
```

So no need of excanvas if you are not concerned by older version of IE.